# stored prcedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to Stored Procedure and I am trying to Create one.

Scenario: I need to fetch data from table 1 and depending upon the output I want to fetch data from Table 2.

Example: My Result should be like below:

```
Table 1                 
package_name               Vendor        applicationname        
TibcoBusnsStudio_360_00    tibco         Tibco Business Studio
```

Table 2

```
Vendor  applicationname        Rel  Ver     Filename                FileSize
Tibco   TIBCO Business Studio   3   3.5.20  tibcobusinessstudio.ini  572
Tibco   TIBCO Business Studio   3   3.8.0   makefile                12912
Tibco   TIBCO Business Studio   3   3.9.0   tibcobusinessstudio     71023
Tibco   TIBCO Business Studio   3   3.7.0   tibcobusinessstudio     71023
```

I tried using the below Code but the while loop hangs.

```
alter procedure proc_MainFile    
(    
@packagename nvarchar(100),    

@appname nvarchar(100) out    
)    
As Begin    
select * from table1 where package_name=@packagename   

while (select Count(applicationname) from table1 where package_name=@packagename)>0
 begin  

   set @appname = (select applicationname from table1 where package_name=@packagename ) 

select * from table2                     
where applicationname like '%' + @appname + '%'  


end    
end  


declare @aplicationname nvarchar(100);                  
execute proc_MainFile @appname=@aplicationname out,@packagename='TibcoBusnsStudio_360_00'                   
select @aplicationname;                 
go
```

Comment: why are you looping? what are you trying to achieve? Do you know anything about JOINs?

Comment: yes I have worked with joins

Comment: Change while to "if".  If count > 0, then run second query.  While is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: I see `package_name` column in your query but you table definition has no relevant column.  Please ensure you provide complete data to get response.  Please look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am not getting the solution to it, if some one of you could guide me in writing//reframing the query

Comment: @techspider --table 1 first Column pkg is package_name..Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I also `applicationname` in your query and it is not in your table.  Please edit your question to reflect correct data.  What is the relation between those two tables? Do you have Primary / Foreign key?

Comment: No, these are independent table no relationship lies between them.Just the application name column has same data.

Comment: Get rid of that loop. Think about this logically...you have a while loop. But inside the loop you are not doing anything that will change the control of the loop. You might as well have written while 1 = 1. The loop itself seems to be completely pointless. Remove it.

Comment: Look at [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) and try to make some attempt with that.

Answer (score 0):

Pure speculation based on the content provided. I think you could redo your procedure to something along these lines.

```
alter procedure proc_MainFile    
(    
    @packagename nvarchar(100)
    , @appname nvarchar(100) out    
) As Begin    

    set nocount on;

    --Using top 1 here in case there is more than 1 row returned.
    select top 1 @appname = t2.applicationname 
    from table2 t2
    join table1 t1 on t1.package_name like '%' + t2.applicationname + '%'                     
    where t1.package_name = @packagename
    order by t2.applicationname
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to re-writing stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE proc_MainFile    
(    
  @packagename nvarchar(100),    
  @appname nvarchar(100) out    
)    
As Begin    
     select * from table1 where package_name=@packagename   
     IF EXISTS(select 1 from table1 where package_name=@packagename)
     begin  
       set @appname = (select applicationname from table1 where package_name=@packagename ) 
       select * from table2 where applicationname like '%' + @appname + '%'  
     end    
end
```

And to call this procedure

```
DECLARE @appname NVARCHAR(100)
EXEC proc_MainFile 'TibcoBusnsStudio_360_00',@appname OUT
SELECT @appname;
```

Comment: I tried using joins and I am getting the Output now.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your valueable inputs.